# Mongodb update field based on another field at a specific time (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

As the title suggests I want a field to be updated automatically at a specific time based on another field.
For example, we have the following schema:

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: [{
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(),
  }],
  var: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0,
  }
});
```

I want to update the field `var` decreasing its value when an element from the array `date` passes 2 hours after inserting it. Let's say I insert a date now in the array `date`, I want 2 hours from now on the variable `var` to automatically decrease his value and at the same time erase the element inserted in `date`.

Comment: I think you could do this logic in a `setInterval`, for example

Comment: This is not really possible purely at the `db` level, you will have to use a different approach to do it.